# Error when creating category programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, magento-2.1.3, magento2.1.5

This is my code saving category:

```
 $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
 $category->setData($this->getCategoryData("Test Test"));
 $category->save();

 protected function getCategoryData($name)
{
    $data = [
        'store_id' => "0",
        'path_ids' => [
            '0' => ""
        ],
        'use_default' => [
            'url_key' => false
        ],
        'use_config' => [
            'available_sort_by' => true,
            'default_sort_by' => true,
            'filter_price_range' => true
        ],
        'id' => "",
        'parent' => "2",
        'path' => "1/2",
        'name' => $name,
        'filter_price_range' => null,
        'url_key' => "",
        'meta_title' => "",
        'is_active' => "1",
        'include_in_menu' => "1",
        'is_anchor' => "1",
        'custom_use_parent_settings' => "0",
        'custom_apply_to_products' => "0",
        'url_key_create_redirect' => "0",
        'description' => "",
        'display_mode' => "PRODUCTS",
        'default_sort_by' => null,
        'meta_keywords' => "",
        'meta_description' => "",
        'custom_layout_update' => "",
        'custom_design_from' => "",
        'custom_design_to' => "",
        'image' => null,
        'parent_id' => "2",
        'available_sort_by' => null,
        'attribute_set_id' => "3",
        'form_key' => 'AUact7MhifCvdSAD'
        ];

    return $data;
}
```

I get the exac $data from category insert form in admin dashboard, But it still throws the exception:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table `catalog_category_flat` doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `catalog_category_flat`.* FROM `catalog_category_flat` WHERE (`catalog_category_flat`.`entity_id`='2')

Is anyone have the solution for fixing this bug ?

**Solution:** I have found the reason why it thrown error.
It is because i turn the **Use Flat Catalog Category** and **Use Flat Catalog Product** to yes.

If you're in the situation like me, turn two configuraions above off, you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to add category programmatically :

http://www.zexperto.com/magento2x/create-category-magento2-programmatically

Comment: I have tried the same solution like that. Please, read carefully my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code to add product

http://www.octonism.com/blog/cat/magento2/post/magento2-programmatically-create-product/

Comment: I have tried the same solution like that. Please, read carefully my question.